# table A with 4-depth category ids, table B with category id-name

Tags: sql, hive

I have a quite specific problem that needs your hint.

Table A

```
productId | category1Id | category2Id | category3Id | category4Id
```

Table B

```
categoryId | categoryName
```

Table A's category 1~4 indicate the depth of the category.

Men(51003) > shirts(52506) > half-sleeve(57516), 
then category1: Men / category2: shirts / category3: half-sleeve

Unfortunately, Table B has no depth but only categoryIds (51003, 52506, ...) and its name.

The result I want looks like:

```
productId | category1Name | category2Name | category3Name | category4Name
```

What kind of joins, unions, or somewhat else should I exploit?

I've tried joining 4 table Bs to each of category level in Table A, but it seemed way too dumb. :(

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your "dumb" method seems like the right approach, so it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's is the only way to get it solve.
I thought it might need pivoting but now I don't thing it will be required.

I would suggest you to go with your solution.

Please find the below solution for exactly your type of requirement.

https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/24103/join-multiple-columns-in-one-table-to-a-single-col.html